# How to show or hide a particular block based upon admin role logged in Magento

Tags: magento, rendering, admin, show-hide, roles

Lets say I have created two admin roles in Magento Role1 and Role2.
I want to show a particular block, lets say 'store-switcher', only when users with role1 are logged in while for users with role2 it should not be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a custom extension or an observer which checks for the logged in Admin User. Depending on the user, you add a custom Design handle. Then using the XML layout system, you remove or add Blocks as you want for your Special handles.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code and knowing where you want to add your block it is hard to say the best way to accomplishing this, but you could try

Take a look @

- [Magento - How to query admin's role name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024564/magento-how-to-query-admins-role-name)
- [Magento: How to get user role from user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796128/magento-how-to-get-user-role-from-user-id)

Then

```
if(role1){
   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mageigniter/storeswitcher')->toHtml();
}
```

See also [How to load a magento view (.phtml) file from a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846451/how-to-load-a-magento-view-phtml-file-from-a-controller)

Comment: Please remember to accept or upvote if my solution solve your issue